# Detecting whether a varchar value is already encrypted by EncryptByPassPhrase() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, encryption, unicode, varbinary

Starting with a `varchar(100)` column named `Password` in a table `Users` with one record in it, after performing an update on the column to encrypt it with `EncryptByPassPhrase()` on the `Password` column the following `varbinary(8000)` string is generated:

> ```
> 0x0342342565CF0....
> ```

...and for simplicity, the string has been abbreviated with `....`.

To be able to store the encrypted `varbinary(8000)` output in the same `Password` column, the encryption function is wrapped `convert(varchar(8000), EncryptByPassPhrase())`.

Running a `select * from Users;` produces this output of its two columns and one record:

> ```
> Name     | Password
> ---------+----------
> Benjamin |
> ```

As you can see, `Password` appears blank. However, running `Select len(Password);`  reveals a value of `52`, so there is definitely a string stored in `Password` and it includes non-printable characters.

So, the question is, how can the blank `varchar(100)` string be tested for its first two varbinary characters being `0x`?

The idea is to create a wrapper encrypt function that decides if the field is already encrypted, not to encrypt it again if it detects that the string passed to it starts with `0x`?

Answer (score 4):

- Never store encrypted passwords. Store one-way hashes of the salted  passwords.
- Don't store a `VARBINARY` value in a `VARCHAR` column lest you risk never getting it back.
- The fact that your client software shows you a hexadecimal representation of a binary string starting with `0x` does not at all mean that `0x` is part of the value.
- There is no reliable way to tell by looking at a sequence of bytes if that sequence is encrypted in any way.